# Symbol Server Delete Command Doesn't Work

Tags: nuget, symbols, symbol-server

I'm preparing to host an internal symbol server for some internal libraries using SymbolSource Community Edition.  While testing the workflow of adding and updating packages, I also tested the ability to delete symbols from the server.  I'm using NuGet.exe to execute commands against the symbol server.  Although the NuGet delete command says that it completed successfully, the files are still on the internal symbol server.  The command that I'm using is:

```
D:\>nuget delete <package name> 0.1.0-alpha <GUID> 
-Source http://localhost/SymbolServer/NuGet/
```

The output from the command is:

```
<package name> 0.1.0-alpha will be deleted from the 'http://localhost/SymbolServer/NuGet/'.
Would you like to continue? (y/N) y

Deleting <package name> 0.1.0-alpha from the 'http://localhost/SymbolServer/NuGet/'.
<package name> 0.1.0-alpha was deleted successfully.
```

Delete functionality (via NuGet) for symbols hosted on SymbolSource.org is mentioned at http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Blog/View/2011-06-27/Deleting_packages_from_SymbolSource.  This functionality really wasn't "delete" functionality, but rather was like a "hide" command.  However, there is a thread at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/symbolsource/delete/symbolsource/Z63nIr_s-DY/V2rDBdsDI2IJ from 2011 that also mentions implementing "full" delete functionality was at the top of the priority list at that point in time.  Anyone know if this functionality was actually implemented?  I can't seem to find any further references to it on the SymbolSource.org site.

When I run Process Monitor on the server to monitor file activity corresponding to executing the NuGet delete command, I can see activity - but the bulk of the activity entries have the status "PATH NOT FOUND" and "NAME NOT FOUND".  The directory that is being referenced in the Process Monitor logs isn't what I would expect.  The primary directory being referenced is:

```
D:\path\to\SymbolSourceApp\NuGet
```

The symbol files, however, are in the directory:

```
D:\path\to\SymbolSourceApp\Data
```

I think I either have to be missing something, or the delete command was never implemented.  Anyone know which might be the case?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.